# Hide user presence contact card popup in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript

On hovering with the mouse over a user presence I don't want to display the contact card.

We have used [this](http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/lync-presence-indicators-code-snippets-in-sharepoint-2013/) to show user presence in a custom Webpart.

Comment: I believe SP has an eventlistener set to show that popup whenever an element with css class `ms-imnlink` is hovered. Try removing the css class.

Comment: you can try this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-it/configuring-online-presence-settings-HA001160802.aspx

Comment: @mbauer, that link is for 2003, this youtube video has the correct apporach but in 2010 clothes (the steps in CA is the same though): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx2RAp_84G8

Comment: Daniel's solution works, but causes a javascript exception to be thrown whenever you hover over the elements with removed classes.